# Battery Notification

Tags: windows-7, laptop, battery

I brought a new Toshiba laptop battery.

It is getting a charge and when unplug power it discharges, but it doesn’t shows the battery notification when the battery becomes low.  Instead it will get shut down without warning.

Can any one tell what will be the problem and how to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 1):

[Try this one](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-sg/windows7/how-do-i-change-the-low-battery-notification)  I think company might disabled during shipment

If you don't have enough time to act after seeing the low and reserve battery notifications, you can increase the percentage of battery remaining for these settings. This can be especially useful for older batteries, which might not have as much storage capacity.

To change low, reserve, and critical power levels

1.
Open Power Options by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, clicking Control Panel, clicking System and Security, and then clicking Power Options.

2.
On the Select a power plan page, next to the plan you want to change, click Change plan settings.

3.
On the Change settings for the plan page, click Change advanced power settings.

4.
On the Advanced settings tab, expand Battery, expand Low battery level, Reserve battery level, and Critical battery level. Change the percentage of battery remaining that you want for each level, and then click OK.